# Array declaration, size definition, and destruction in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

So I'm unsure as to what the correct way is to do this. I have a class named someClass, with a private variable that is an array of integers. The size doesn't get defined until the constructor is called. Here's how I do it:

In someClass.h:

```
class someClass {
public:
    someClass();
    someClass(int size);
    ~someClass();
private:
    int* array;
}
```

In someClass.cpp:

```
someClass::someClass() {
    array = new int[9];
}

someClass::someClass(int range) {
    array = new int[range];
}

someClass::~someClass() {
    delete[] array;
}
```

Did I declare/define the array correctly? Would it have been much better to use a vector?

Is the destructor correct?

Comment: That isn't an array, it's a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're doing it correctly (partially), and yes, it would be better to use a `std::vector` (because of the "partially" part).

The "partially" is that now you will have to provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator for your class (and for efficiency, you might want to have a move constructor and move assignment operator as well); if you don't, you'll get double deletion errors if you ever copy the class.

`std::vector` encapsulates all this, so this is why you should prefer it. Not to mention that it has nice features like iterators.

Your class would then look like this:

```
class someClass {
public:
    someClass();
    someClass(int size);
    //no destructor necessary!
private:
    std::vector<int> array;
}
```

```
someClass::someClass()
{} // nothing special needed

someClass::someClass(int range) : array(range)
{}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening with that second-to-last line? The one saying `someClass::someClass(int range) : array(range)`?

Comment: @Rstevoa It's calling the size-setting constructor of `std::vector`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/1782465) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You should also add copy ctor and copy assignment operator. Remember the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)!